# Model Validation with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.6

I have this code:

```
//Edit page
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    MyObj myobj = db.MyObj.First(s=>s.id == id);
    return View(myobj);
}

//Save the edition
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string id, MyObj myobj)
{
    if( !ModelState.IsValid ) return View(myobj);
    //Continue saving...
}
```

So, if the data passed is wrong the model validation fails and return the obj with the data annotation, the problem is that I lost my parameter in the url.

The edit url is  http://xxx/controller/Edit/1234 and the next one is http://xxx/controller/Edit  (without the parameter)

Comment: try 
       return View()
instead of return View(myobj)

Comment: Nop System.NullReferenceException reading model and the url without the parameter

Comment: That looks like it is down to the route values set on the html.beginform to me

Comment: Post your view form.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, MyObj myobj)
{
    if( !ModelState.IsValid ){
    ViewBag.Obj=myobj;
    return RedirectToAction("Edit",new{id=id});  
    }
    //Continue saving...
}
```

Comment: But ViewBag.Obj=myobj;  is not the @Model object, and I'm not sure if you get also the validation messages of the errors to show its on the view